# Cannot instantiate the type EventHandler

Tags: event-handling, instantiation

```
if (savedInstanceState != null)                 
    mHandler = new EventHandler(Main.this, mFileMag, savedInstanceState.getString("location"));

else
    mHandler = new EventHandler(Main.this, mFileMag);
```

Error is

> Cannot instantiate the type EventHandler

How can I solve this Error?